# Username & Host Name are Screwed on Terminal

Tags: command-line, dns, hostname

I have been working on my machine to setup a web server.
At a certain point, I noticed my username & host name displayed at the very beginning of each line of terminal commands are different from the real information (see the screenshot).

- Real username: ebooks
- Real hostname: ebooks-vps
- Displayed header: ns1 (the host name of the DNS server)

[terminal_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWfeP.png)

Actually, I have setup Bind9 DNS server. "ns1" is the host name of that DNS server. All the servers (Apache2 & DNS) are installed on the same virtual machine.

I noticed this change when I did one of the following commands.

```
host -a localhost 
host -a localhost.domainname
host -a 127.0.0.1
```

How can I get the terminal display back to normal? (the commands are being properly performed though.)

OS Version: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Desktop 64bit

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $PS1`?

Comment: It's like this: 'ebooks@ebooks-vps
ns1:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
ebooks@ebooks-vps
ns1:~$ '